# Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) - What is SecretPrepend and SecretAppend for?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, diffie-hellman

I was just playing with `ECDiffieHellmanCng` and I wonderd what `SecretAppend` and `SecretPrepend` could be for. Google wasn't so helpfull. Any Idea?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.secretappend.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.secretprepend.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just generating a secret value is generally not enough to generate a key using key agreement. Although the secret should contain enough entropy for a symmetric key, it is unlikely to be uniformly distributed. Hence a key agreement should - at least in theory - contain a key based key derivation function. Now these key derivation functions have optional parameters to derive specific keys. The methods you pointed to may be used to supply these additional parameters.

Normally, for new protocols, it is probably best to not use these properties. If you require multiple keys, perform an additional key based key derivation function on the output (or use SHA-512, and extract two keys). Other implementations may not supply these parameters at all. It's probably best to only use these properties if an existing protocol requires them.

Comment: So it is like a salt for the key agreement so if I'm using ECDiffieHellmanCng I could but 512 Bytes from PBKDF2 in SecretAppend and SecretPrepend? With no harm to secruity?

Comment: I jsut run the code, the SecretAppend and SecretPrepend msut be the same on both sides. So it is like an IV it can be send in Plaintext without disclose information?

Comment: Normally it should contain identifiers for the kind of key you are generating. Those parameters themselves are normally not secret (although they *could* be). Normally they are not send, because they are known it advance. E.g. for a data key, the parameters could include an ASCII encoding of `"DataKey_0"`. You could take a look at NIST SP 800-108 and 132 for more precise information.

Comment: Are you still missing things from this answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But I still don't understand the why there is a append and prepend value.

Comment: Try and create the ECDH class, generating a new key pair. Then set one of these properties to two different values, say the ASCII encoding of `"ENC"` and `"MAC"`. Then call the `DeriveKeyMaterial` after setting each. You will likely end up with two different key values. Now this likely performs the full recalculation - including the asymmetric part, so it's not that useful. But you could be using a protocol that requires `"SESSION_KEY"` to be pre-pended to the secret. Try it out, see what happens!